# How to get the value of editable column of datagrid and on which event

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a datagrid in C#.net I have made some columns in grid editable. On which event should i get the value user has entered in the grid and how to get the value user has entered?

Comment: you can use "CellEndEdit" event, it will fire when user end editing the cell of gridview

Comment: please add some code. What is a `grid`? or is it  `DataGridView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event: CellEndEdit

Value: `(your datagridview).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value`

(Note: this is object type. You can use ToString() method to convert it to string)

Answer (score 0):

If your grid is named dataGridView1 then the code below is what you need:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.RowIndex >= 0) // Ignore clicks on the header row that changes sorting
            {
                // do what you need here
            }
}
```